# Where can I read the prize-winning AI-generated sci-fi short novel 《机忆之地》?

Tags: chinese-language

In [recent news](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/science/article/3245725/chinese-professor-used-ai-write-science-fiction-novel-then-it-won-national-award), a Tsinghua professor 沈阳 entered an AI-written 5915-character story called《机忆之地》 into a Chinese science-fiction literature competition 第五届江苏省青年科普科幻作品大赛 (I believe [this](http://m.52jingsai.com/article-19732.html) is the competition's webpage); see also [the backstory](https://www.tsinghua.org.cn/info/1954/39904.htm) (in Chinese) and [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_Memories).  From what I understand, the novel won a [二等奖](https://www.guancha.cn/economy/2023_12_13_718893_s.shtml) = "second-rank prize".

I'd like to read it in Chinese (although it's called a novel, it's very short, so it'd make good reading practice).  However, I haven't been able to find it via Google.

**Question**: Where can I read the prize-winning AI-generated sci-fi short novel 《机忆之地》?

Comment: Hmm, what's the copyright status of AI-generated stories? (I wonder if that would make a good separate question ...)

Comment: @Randal'Thor As the AI models don't do anything on their own but rather produce some output given the prompts of some human being, that human being owns the copy right. The legal concept is the same as if you use a typewriter to write your story. The copyright belongs to the human doing the typing not to the typewriter.

Comment: @quarague I doubt that it is quite that simple. Generative AI relies on training with existing content, which is usually copyrighted. The AI system's output may contain copyrighted content without being able to identify its provenance. [Generative AI is a minefield for copyright law](https://theconversation.com/generative-ai-is-a-minefield-for-copyright-law-207473).

Comment: @Tsundoku That is true. I was mostly explaining that the AI itself certainly does not hold any rights to the work.